# Can't run a testsuite with phpunit

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am trying to do a phpunit testsuite inside my "Homestead" vagrant box.
I have like 12 tests only..

It was working fine, but suddenly I cant run it anymore.. It give me this error:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code/ticketbeast$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 7.5.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

......PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/vagrant/code/ticketbeast/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php on line 315
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /home/vagrant/code/ticketbeast/vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/FatalErrorException.php on line 1

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/vagrant/code/ticketbeast/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php on line 315

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /home/vagrant/code/ticketbeast/vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/FatalErrorException.php on line 1
```

Comment: Are you able to pin down which test is causing the error? Try adding the flag "--testdox" to see which ones have been completed up until this point.

Comment: @Zakalwe The tests are not the issue. When I test them one by one .. they are working fine.. the issue is happening when I do a full test-suite with "./vendor/bin/phpunit"

Comment: Ok, there was a test I missed to test alone.. which has the issue... thanks for  "--testdox" helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was a (callback function) inside some test was causing the problem for me. Everything works now.